# Jobs: wrong links in "Your Recent Searches" and "Manage job alerts"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, search

On a regular job search, the `searchTerm` `GET` parameter holds the value of the query (For example: `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=foo`). The links in "Your Recent Searches" and "Manage job alerts", hold the query in the `q` `GET` parameter (For example: `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=foo&c=USD&rs=1`), which search in the Q&A itself.

#### Summary:

In these pages, the wrong `GET` query parameter is used (`q` instead of `searchTerm`).

Comment: Update: as far as I can see, it's all OK now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! Thanks for the report, @Shamuel! We were refactoring code in that area and obviously missed something.:/ It should all be fixed now.